How do i change the monitor numbers?
I have 2 monitors and my primary is set as number 2. Games keep opening on the other monitor that is set as number 1. I am trying to make it so that my primary monitor is set to number 1 and the one i use for chats/youtube is number 2. How do i switch them? I am on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS and using GNOME.

Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please mention the Ubuntu version and whether you use GNOME or Wayland by editing the question.

Added the ubuntu version and whether i use gnome or wayland.

Have you tried just switching the monitor cables over so that 2 is plugged into where you have 1 now and 1 plugged into where you have 2 now?

I tried but my other monitor is not HDMI. its a DVI. I switched the DVI port alot but couldnt get it to change. There seems to be another HDMI (unsure about this) port on my GPU but my port wont fit in.

Does this answer your question: How to open application on a specific display in Ubuntu 20.04??

This question is similar to: How to open application on a specific display in Ubuntu 20.04. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
